# Is there a way to programatically burn an ISO to USB?

Tags: c#, usb, iso, bootable

I need to be able to make a self extracting image which will burn itself to a USB stick.

I'm thinking if there is a freeware tool (something like Rufus or MagicISO) which supports command line I may be able to put some kind of shell wrapper to detect the USB flash drive, and give it a GUI where the user can confirm they want to create an bootable ISO to that drive.

The self extracting file will also have to contain the ISO. The end result I am after is something like the [Windows 10 Media Creation tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/software-download/windows10).

I would like to do this with C# .Net - it will be to run on a Windows platform.

Comment: obviously it is possible.. all the other apps that burn disks use programming too, not magic.. so maybe post some info about which language and platform youre talking about so people can answer your questiuon...

Comment: Fair comment - forgot that!